# oracle select query inside nvl

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to update a database column with a page item vaue. If the page item is null then I want to replace it with a value returned from sql select query.

```
update user 
    set pswd := nvl(:P10_PSWD,select pswd from user where uname=:P10_UNAME), utype=:P10_UTYPE  where uname=:P10_UNAME;
```

I want to update column- utype and paswd. If item :P10_PSWD is null then I want to update pswd with existing value and utype with :P10_UTYPE . How to do this?

Comment: The assignment operator in **SQL** (and thus for an `UPDATE` statement) is `=`. You only need `:=` in **PL/SQL** to assign variables.

Comment: Hi, I have a change in my query and details. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: And if :P10_PSWD is **not** `NULL`, then do you or do you not want to update `utype`? You need to clarify that as well. Also, you changed the query but you still have the incorrect `:=` instead of `=` for the first assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to use a subquery; if you want to use a value from a column in the current row, just use its name.

It seems you want something like

```
update user 
    set pswd = nvl(:P10_PSWD, pswd), utype = :P10_UTYPE  
    where uname=:P10_UNAME;
```

However, it is still not clear, even after your changes, if you want `utype` to be updated in all cases, or only when `:P10_PSWD` is `NULL`. The `UPDATE` above will update `utype` regardless. If you only want it updated when `:P10_PSWD` is `NULL`, then the assignment to `utype` should be

```
 .....  , utype = nvl2(:P10_PSWD, utype, :P10_UTYPE)
 .....
```

NVL2 function: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions106.htm

Comment: don't use `user` as a table name ( reserved word )

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan - That is what the OP had in the original question. We can safely assume the OP doesn't **really** have a table by that name (the DB wouldn't accept it), so I chose to leave it alone and not comment on it. But yes, you are 100% right - a table can't be named `user`.

Comment: I want to update utype in all cases.yea. it is users, not user. .I'm a new born here.. sorry. and thank you for the support.

Comment: ok one more doubt, if pswd was from another table, How can i do this?

Comment: @Nidheesh , Ask that as a separate question , you have already updated your question few times.

Comment: Updating values in one table based on values from a different table is a very different question from what you asked initially. As Kaushik says - start a different thread for that. **Or not**: Look around first, search for "Oracle update through join" - you will find plenty of similar questions (I know, I answered many of them already).

Answer (score 2):

This  UPDATE makes the requested change:

If the bind variable is set the password is updated, if the bind variable is NULL the original password of the user is preserved.

```
update userw 
    set pswd  =  :P10_PSWD
where  :P10_PSWD is not NULL and uname=:P10_UNAME;
```

Comment: Hi, I have a change in my query and details

Answer (score 1):

You are having same `uname=:P10_UNAME`   in your `where` clause and `NVL` select, which is  not necessary, you can simply use.

```
UPDATE user
    SET
        pswd  = NVL(:p10_pswd,pswd),
        utype = :p10_utype
WHERE
    uname = :p10_uname;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are to handle utype value also if required.but it wont throw and exception and instead it will update with null. I would say best method is if null then keep the existing. then again that depend on your requirement.

```
 update user
 set    pswd  = nvl(:P10_PSWD,pswd),
        utype = nvl(:P10_UTYPE,utype)
 where  uname = :P10_UNAME;
```